# Get three specific wordpress posts and random the output

Tags: php, wordpress

I've this wordpress `get_posts` arguments:

```
    $arg = array(
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'dmd_berater',
        'post_name' => 'test1',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'dmd_subject',
            'value' => 'Daten und Analysen',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    );
    $consultant_post = get_posts($arg); //contains ALL posts.
```

The code above contains all posts but I only want the post with the `post_name` 'test1'.

Is this possible? And how?

It should be great if I can output three specific posts. I think it should be work with an array? Like:

```
'post_name' => array('test1', 'test2', 'test3'),
```

1. Can somebody find my issue?
2. Is an array possible?

Comment: `post_name` field is used for slug are you sure you want to get 3 posts by their slug ?

Comment: What is your current WP version? @cgee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'post_name__in' => array('test1', 'test2', 'test3')`

See [the paramters section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) for more informations.

Comment: Works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want 'test1' is the slug of the post, then use just 'name' => 'test1'.

-->[here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Get_a_post_by_its_slug) is the link

return value of get_posts is an array

--> [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Return_Value)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [**WP_QUERY()**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and its parameter [**`post_name__in`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

According to DOCS

> 'post_name__in' - Preserve post slug order given in the post_name__in
>   array (available since Version 4.6).

```
$arg   = array(
    'orderby'       => 'rand',
    'numberposts'   => 3,
    'post_type'     => 'dmd_berater',
    'post_name__in' => array('test1', 'test2', 'test3'),
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'dmd_subject',
            'value'   => 'Daten und Analysen',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        // Your loop code
    endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop('Sorry, no posts were found');
endif;
```